# How to Create a file myfile.txt under some aribtrary directories and tar them in Java

Tags: java, file, directory

I need to create a tar file which would have directories and files underneath. Example:

```
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    String dir = itr.next();
    File f = new File("/tmp/apps/"+dir);
    f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    File contentFile = new File(f, "myfile.txt");
    if(!contentFile.exists()) {
        contentFile.createNewFile(); 
    }
    Writer out = new FileWriter(contentFile);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(out);
    bw.write(someString);
    bw.close();
}
//tar the content from /tmp/apps as apps.tar which sould have some directories 
and files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the JDK itself that would be helpful for you. I would recommend you add a dependency on Apache Commons-Compress ( http://commons.apache.org/compress/ ).

See TarArchiveOutputStream and TarArchiveEntry in the documentation : http://commons.apache.org/compress/examples.html#tar

Does it help ?

Comment: Its actually commons-compress. Working on it right now. will update tomorrow.

Comment: Okay, I finally ended up using jTar, another apache licensed tool to create tar archive. I was able to successfully add files and folders with files in a tar file.